# Google таблица, нужна помощь с формулой массива

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть формула в google таблице "реестр договоров", которая составляет номер договора по нескольким параметрам, такие как дата внесения договора, количество дней отсрочки, регион. Вот эта формула:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(F416));IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A416));NOT(ISBLANK(F416));NOT(ISBLANK(C416)));"";CONCATENATE(LEFT(YEAR(D416);2);".";A416;"/";IF(H416="Предоплата";"П";H416);"-";I416));"")
```

Можно переделать формулу так, чтобы она работала как формула массива на всю таблицу?
[ссылка-пример](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3ZvbU31dYZ0c9oP9ZicpdgPcJBY2AZ8WBCAICwm6nw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Странная у Вас формула... `NOT(ISBLANK(A2))` - короче `A2<>""`. Не нужно второй раз проверять `AND(...NOT(ISBLANK(F2));...)`, эта проверка есть в первом `IF`. Почему при наличии значений в трех ячейках `A2, F2, C2` сцеплять не нужно, а при пустой хотя бы одной из них формировать номер? Берете год из ячейки`D2`, но нет проверки на наличие даты. Нет проверки и на наличие значения в `I2`. Вы бы описали в первом сообщении полнее задачу (как, при  каких условиях формировать номер договора)

Comment: Дополнение: Такой вариант - `A2<>""` -  ошибется, если в ячейке будет пустая текстовая строка "". Такое может быть при копировании значения в ячейку или в результате работы формулы. В Вашей таблице такого нет. Но даже при наличии текста нулевой длины можно писать проще, чем `NOT(ISBLANK(A2))` - в завистмости от значения `ISTEXT(A2)` или  `ISNUMBER(A2)`

Comment: Да теперь вижу, вчера было всего 30 мин на полную переделку старого реестра, поэтому очень спешил. Над формулой надо еще поработать.

Comment: Вот с такого и начинаются перерасходы бюджета или потери в бизнесе :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Предупреждение. Лично я считаю нелепостью генерацию динамических
> номеров договоров. Номер - это индекс, статический элемент,
> обусловленный входящими данными, генерируемый **ОДНАЖДЫ**.

Множественная конкатенация не поддерживается формулами массива, поэтому используют либо конкатенацию через `&`, либо [побочные эффекты других формул](https://contributor.pw/post/google-sheets-join-everithing-with-formula/).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF((A2:A="")*(C2:C="")*(F2:F="");
  "-";
  TEXT(D2:D;"yy\.")&A2:A&"/"&IF(H2:H="Предоплата";"П";H2:H)&"-"&I2:I)
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Это то что нужно! 